# Is it possible to read all properties configured for a user profile sync connection using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-userprofile

Is it possible to read all the fields that was set to create a user profile sync connection .
So far I was only able to get the Display Name of the Connection.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
 SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
 UserProfileConfigManager upcm = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);
 ConnectionManager cm = upcm.ConnectionManager;
     foreach (Connection cn in cm)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Connection Name " + cn.DisplayName);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean `property` instead of `fields`

Yes it is possible with the use of `reflection`.

```
foreach (Connection cn in cm)
{
    var properties = cn.GetType()
                       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                       .Where(i => i.CanRead)
    foreach(var property in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(cn));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great in getting the properties. But couldn't get what i was looking for, to get the configured password.